# CMD START command is opening a different .exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, terminal

I have a super weird problem. I have two versions of an application (2018 and 2019). I want to open the 2019 one.

- *2018: "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\bin\maya.exe"*
- *2019: "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\bin\maya.exe"*

When I run:
`"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\bin\maya.exe"` it opens up 2019 perfectly.

When I run:
`START "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\bin" maya.exe` it opens up 2018 (WHAT!?)

When I manually go to the `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\bin` folder and double click `maya.exe` myself, it opens up 2019 correctly.

**`START` is causing something weird, can anyone help me figure out what is happening?**

Comment: The reason is clearly explained in the help information. To see that, open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key. You are running `maya.exe` with the Title `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\bin`. The current directory is searched for a file named `maya.exe`, and runs it if possible, if not found, it searches each location in `%PATH%`, in listing order, and runs the first one it finds.

Comment: `START "" /D "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\bin" maya.exe`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run START "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\bin\maya.exe"

You probably have "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\bin" in your path.

Comment: I don't know why someone gave you a downvote, but this was exactly my problem!